# Float Object not callable gaussian pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sure this has been asked a million times, but I am very new to python and cannot understand many of the existing posts for this, so my apologies. I am having to code out a Gaussian PDF for a base level Python class than I am in. IDLE is giving me a TypeError and saying that the object is not callable. I understand that this has something to do with my parenthesis, and how I might have put a number right next to one, and it thought I was trying to call a function but is mad because functions can't start with numbers. If someone could show me the error in my code that would be dandy. My code is the following

```py
pi = 3.141592653589793

e = 2.718281828459045
x = 7.0

mean = 5.0

stddev = 1.5

print((1/(stddev)*((2.0*pi)**0.5)))*(e**-(1/2)((x-mean)/stddev)**2)
```

Comment: In `-(1/2)((x-mean)/stddev)` you are calling the float returned by (1/2). Perhaps you want to multiply instead, i.e., `-(1/2) * ((x-mean)/stddev)`

Comment: you can format your code by wrapping it in ``` ` ```

Comment: pi = 3.141592653589793
e = 2.718281828459045

x = 7.0
mean = 5.0
stddev = 1.5
print(((1)/(stddev)*((2.0*pi)**0.5)))*((e)**(-1)*(1/2)((x-mean)/stddev)**2)

Comment: I have now significantly changed my code to that to see if it would do me any luck. Also I will try what you said Justin, but I don't know what Cyril meant

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should enter math formula in python:

```
pi = 3.141592653589793

e = 2.718281828459045 

x = 7.0

mean = 5.0

stddev = 1.5

# this following is incorrect, has mismatched parenthesis
print((1/(stddev)*((2.0*pi)*0.5)))*(e-(1/2)*((x-mean)/stddev)**2)

# this is what I think you meant:
part1 = 1/(stddev)*((2.0*pi)*0.5)
part2 = e-(1/2)*((x-mean)/stddev)
print( part1 * (part2) **2)
```

Basically, you cannot omit `*` when you need a multiply symbol.

Also your parenthesis is messed up in original code, it would be helpful to separate them out.

Comment: Thank you. I got it all figured out before this but this is essentially the fix I used.